# Define a dummy static variable within a class

Tags: python

I want to define, inside a class, an static empty instance of that class, to use as a default value in some functions:

```
class Pref(object):
  def __init__(self,a,b):
      ...

  __dummy = Pref(None,None)

  ...

  def combine(self, other_pref=__dummy):
      ...
```

But, this gives an error that Pref is not defined.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Seems like a bad design. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @tuxtimo see my edit: I have some functions that need another Pref as an argument, and I want to have a certain dummy Pref as a default argument.

Comment: The name of a class is not defined until *after* the definition completes. Why not have a class method `@classmethod` `def dummy(cls): return cls(None, None)` to create the dummy? Make the default value `None` then check e.g. `if other_pref is None: other_pref = self.dummy()`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe There is only one dummy Pref and it doesn't change. Isn't it wasteful to create a new one each time?

Comment: If your application is not too time critical it's absolutely fine. Another good way would be to have None as the default argument and create the object in the method. It's anyway better if you have a new object each time because only this way you can be sure that you have a valid fresh object.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to implement it, using a class method to initialise a class attribute:

```
class Pref(object):

    _dummy = None

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        ...

    @classmethod
    def dummy(cls):
        if cls._dummy is None:
            cls._dummy = cls(None, None)
        return cls._dummy  

    def combine(self, other_pref=None):
        if other_pref is None:
            other_pref = self.dummy()
        ...

    ...
```

Note changes to your code style, per [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Only use the `_dummy` cache variable if you don't care about changes in the object ...

Comment: @tuxtimo or if you *don't make any* - but yes, as written changes to the "dummy" would be seen elsewhere.